# Is this integral divergent?

Tags: integration

I have this integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \sin(\theta) e^{\cos{\theta}}\, d\theta.$$

So if I use the substitution $u = \cos{\theta}$ and $du = -\sin{\theta}\, d{\theta}$, it becomes

$$- \int_0^{\infty} e^u \, du.$$

Now I must consider

$$\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{\cos\theta} \Biggr|_{0}^{t}, $$

but what is $e^{\cos{\theta}}$ when t goes to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

As you've suspected, the limit does not exist because $\exp\cos t$ fluctuates periodically between the extrema $\exp\pm 1$.

Comment: @CarlMummert Whoops!  I've deleted my comments.